# C Linux sockets for interprocess communication, how to handle mutual exclusion?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, interprocess, mutual-exclusion

I have a Linux host system where I have different process that send information by an unix socket to another process. The idea was to use a socket that receives all the data for the rest of the process. But I read that sockets are not safe-thread and I don't know how I can mantain the mutual exclusion using differents process.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Where did you _read that sockets are not safe-thread_?

Comment: The easiest (and I think best) approach is not to share your socket file-descriptors across threads (or processes).  Rather, set up a connection and make sure that the socket on each end of the connection is handled by exactly one thread, which can safely use it to communicate with the one thread holding the socket at the other end of the connection.

Comment: Apart from sockets being thread-safe ... There are two types of UNIX domain sockets: datagram and stream. With datagram each `send` will send a message to the peer and this will be atomar, i.e. two datagrams send at the same time will not somehow overlap. With stream sockets each connection at the sender will result in a different connection at the peer - therefore there is also a clear separation builtin.

Comment: The main problem with multiple threads accessing the same socket-file-descriptor isn't the socket itself, but rather the data moving across the socket; it's easy in that scenario for the data from different threads to get mixed up and therefore difficult to interpret.

Comment: If you're trying to communicate with _processes_ (and/or threads) on the same system via unix domain sockets, I've found that SysV IPC (`msgsnd/msgrcv`) can be more flexible. You can use _one_ message queue for all threads (vs. needing a separate socket for communication between any two given processes). And they work just fine for  multiple producer/multiple consumer scenarios.